# How to output the linux command and the returned result in the same text file?

Tags: command-line

All the commands I've seen so far look like `command > file` or `command >> file`, which output the result to the designated file. For instance, when I type `openssl version > lab4.txt`, all I see in the text file is `OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013`.

What if I want to output both the command I typed and the result that was returned one below the other like this?

```
linux2[20]% openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: from bash `set -x;exec | tee file` might be handy.

Answer (score 6):

The redirection operator `command > file` will redirect the STDOUT of a command, or STDERR of a command if used like `command 2> file` or both if used like `&>` in bash or in any shell by portable `command > file 2>&1` way. I am not aware of any direct method using redirection that can achieve what you need.

Although it is possible using the `script` program. It will basically save everything printed on the terminal in that `script` session.

From `man script`:

```
script makes a typescript of everything printed on your terminal. 
It is useful for students who need a hardcopy record of an 
interactive session as proof of an assignment, as the typescript file 
can be printed out later with lpr(1).
```

You can start a `script` session by just typing `script` in the terminal, all the subsequent commands and their outputs will all be saved in a file named `typescript` in the current directory. You can save the result to a different file too by just starting `script` like:

```
script output.txt
```

To logout of the `screen` session (stop saving the contents), just type `exit`.

Here is an example:

```bsh
$ script output.txt
Script started, file is output.txt

$ ls
output.txt  testfile.txt  foo.txt

$ exit
exit
Script done, file is output.txt
```

Now if i read the file:

```bsh
$ cat output.txt

Script started on Mon 20 Apr 2015 08:00:14 AM BDT
$ ls
output.txt  testfile.txt  foo.txt
$ exit
exit

Script done on Mon 20 Apr 2015 08:00:21 AM BDT
```

`script` also has many options e.g. running quietly `-q` (`--quiet`) without showing/saving program messages, it can also run a specific command `-c` (`--command`) rather than a session, it also has many other options. Check `man script` to get more idea.

Comment: Good to know. It is useful for making tutorials and related stuff.

Comment: @rpax: Yes, it is :)

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create a script with the following:
`echo 'command -params/r' > file.lst`
`command -params >> file.lst`